using Twilio step on Zapier for dyanmic set of receives/messages
I have a code-by-Zapier step that returns this:
console.log({inputData});

return {"messages":[
  {"to":"+17375554824","val":"hi there alex"},
  {"to":"+17375554829","val":"hi there bob"},
  {"to":"+14155554822","val":"hi there charlie"}
]};

but in the next step, the Twilio step, I just see this:

I looked online and I am told I can use like {{Loop_messages.val}} or {{Loop_messages.to}}
but I don't really see how to do that with the UI for the Twilio step. Anyone know?

You'll need to implement a loop step in your Zap before the Twilio step to loop through all "to" phone numbers and the respective "val" that needs to be sent as a message.
There's a guide on implementing looping here: https://help.zapier.com/hc/en-us/articles/8496106701453-Loop-your-Zap-actions#h_01HME0XPHPAMF4BQ4A6KH9D645.
Ideally, there will be one loop iteration for each phone number and the respective val, which you can then map into the Twilio step (the guide covers this too).
